# Bugged C Implementation of Straight Insertion sorting

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

A beginner in C, i'm attempting to implement a Straight Insertion sort.
My code has a bug, but i struggle to put my finger on it. If someone experience could point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated !!

A few points :

- The variable `sizeTable` is the dimension of the array (10). It shouldn't change at any stage, yet when exiting the sorting algorithm, it's worth 100.
- The code was running fine with values from 10 down to 1 (i.o. 100 down to 10).
- I use different variable names (namely `aSize`, `mySize` & `sizeTable` for the array dimension argument on purpose (making sure i understand passing arguments to functions). However using one single variable name doesn't change anything (thankfully!).
- When i run in CodeChef, i get a runtime error whereas in CodeBlocks, i obtain a 100-elements array, 10 first ones being the initial array properly sorted, and the balance random values from the memory. Why so ? (that's a subsidiary question...)

Thanks in advance !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printTable(int myTable[], int aSize);
void straightInsertion(int myTable[], int mySize);

int main()
{

    int sizeTable = 10;
    int myTable[10] = {100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10};

    printTable(myTable, sizeTable);
    straightInsertion(myTable, sizeTable);
    printf("\n");
    printTable(myTable, sizeTable);


    return 0;
}

//Loop to display the array
void printTable(int myTable[], int aSize)
{
    int  i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", myTable[i]);
    }
}

//Sorting algo
void straightInsertion(int myTable[], int mySize)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;
    for(j = 1; j<= mySize; j++)
    {
        temp = myTable[j];
        i = j-1;
        while(i>=0 && myTable[i] > temp)
        {
            myTable[i+1] = myTable[i];
            i--;
        }
        myTable[i+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple bounds error.  You have:

```
for(j = 1; j<= mySize; j++)
```

You should be using:

```
for (j = 1; j < mySize; j++)
```

to avoid overwriting the end of the array.

Good work on the use of the printing function.  May I recommend that you add `putchar('\n');` in the function to avoid needing to use `printf("\n");` in the calling code.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for the correction and the suggestion. I'm reading the definitions between `printf` and `putchar`, but do not really grasp the difference. Is `putchar` more appropriate because i'm only intending to output one single character (i.e. change of line), making `printf` overkill for this purpose ?

Comment: Yes; using `putchar('\n');` is slightly more direct than using `printf("\n");` — but you'd be hard pressed to measure a performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring and correcting your `straightInsertion` function

```
void straightInsertion(int myTable[], int mySize) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < mySize; ++i) {
        int tmp = myTable[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && myTable[j - 1] > tmp; j--)
            myTable[j] = myTable[j - 1];
        myTable[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a stylistic point, I always cringe when I see loops without braces.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite Correctly indenting the code won't let you.

Comment: And other people, @ThePcLuddite, cringe when they see single-statement loop bodies wrapped in braces.  It is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you used:

`for(j = 1; j<= mySize; j++)`

Remember that arrays in C are zero-indexed, meaning an array's first index is at 0, not 1, so its last index is going to be `mySize - 1`. That means that accessing `myTable[mySize]` is always going to be out of bounds, and accessing that address is undefined behavior.

If you change the line to

`for(j = 1; j < mySize; j++)`

the code works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanantion. So i should take it I got lucky the code run despite the bounds error when array was {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} in CodeBlocks. I note it generates a runtime in CodeChef (rightly so).

Comment: @error404: The C standard doesn't define what will happen when you invoke undefined behaviour, such as accessing an array out of bounds (if you access an element beyond the end, or before the start, of an array).  I changed the code to `int myTable[] = { 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 55 };` and left the size at 10; the 55 appeared between 50 and 60 and 100 vanished. But the code could make your computer erase its hard drive; that would also be legitimate, but improbable, not least because compiler writers occasionally make mistakes too, and don't like their disk drive being erased.

Comment: Then i'll keep using online IDEs for fiddling with code, as i'd rather have their harddrives erased than mine !! I tried your last stunt, and note that CodeChef behaves more reasonably, ignoring the eleventh element and sorting the array correctly. In the same vein, it was issuing a runtime error rather with the buggy code, rather than the erratic behaviour displayed by CodeBlocks on my local machine.

Comment: @error404 Just so you know, Jonathan Leffler was just using the "erase hard drive" as an example that anything could happen. Having your hard drive completely erased would still follow the standard. But if the compiler made dancing unicorns run across your screen, that would also follow the standard. The standard doesn't define what should happen when you index an array outside of its bounds. However, no C compiler does either of those things, so you don't have to worry about your hard drive being erased.